# Unable to remove Server HTTP header with Varnish 5

Tags: http, varnish, http-headers

I have the following `vcl_deliver` subroutine:

```
sub vcl_deliver {

 # Remove some HTTP-headers:
 unset resp.http.Server;
 unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
 unset resp.http.Via;
 unset resp.http.X-Cacheable;
 unset resp.http.Age;

 return (deliver);
}
```

Now the strange thing is that every other HTTP header get's removed except the `Server` header (I've checked with `curl` and with Google Chrome). When I debug with `varnishlog -g raw`, I get the following information:

```
202443 RespProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
202443 RespStatus     c 200
202443 RespReason     c OK
202443 RespHeader     c Server: nginx
202443 RespHeader     c Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
202443 RespHeader     c Vary: Accept-Encoding
202443 RespHeader     c Cache-Control: no-cache, private
202443 RespHeader     c Date: Sun, 12 Aug 2018 14:19:11 GMT
202443 RespHeader     c X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
202443 RespHeader     c X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
202443 RespHeader     c X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
202443 RespHeader     c Content-Encoding: gzip
202443 RespHeader     c X-Varnish: 202443 168601
202443 RespHeader     c Age: 69910
202443 RespHeader     c Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.0)
202443 VCL_call       c DELIVER                                                                                                            [7/171]
202443 RespUnset      c Server: nginx
202443 RespUnset      c X-Varnish: 202443 168601
202443 RespUnset      c Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.0)
202443 RespUnset      c Age: 69910
202443 VCL_return     c deliver
202443 Timestamp      c Process: 1534153462.090447 0.000147 0.000147
202443 RespUnset      c Content-Encoding: gzip
202443 RespHeader     c Accept-Ranges: bytes
202443 Debug          c "RES_MODE 40"
202443 RespHeader     c Connection: close
202443 Gzip           c U D - 0 0 0 0 0
202443 Timestamp      c Resp: 1534153462.090535 0.000235 0.000088
202443 ReqAcct        c 229 0 229 302 0 302
202443 End            c
202442 SessClose      c REQ_CLOSE 0.000
202442 End            c
```

As we can seee (`RespUnset Server: nginx`) Varnish is trying to remove the HTTP `Server` header - but why does it still appear when I debug with `curl` or Google Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using Varnish with nginx "sandwich" for SSL termination:

> nginx (SSL) -> Varnish -> nginx

So naturally, after removing `Server`header in Varnish, the nginx (SSL) still sends a header of its own.

The solution is to [remove the Server header in nginx as well](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/how-to-remove-the-server-header-in-nginx), e.g. using headers-more nginx module:

```
more_clear_headers Server;
```

Comment: Very good, MOLODEZ!